# HERE-API - how to provide/inherit JS object to python

Tags: javascript, python, variables, here-api

Everything works fine, but I do not know how to import JS object variable into python.

In main.js I have a variable:

```
var markerWroclaw = new H.map.Marker({ lat: 51.0, lng: 17.0 }, { icon: icon });
```

Also I've created *.py file, let's call it python_js.py.

In normal python way if I want to import something to python_js.py, I will do that:

```
from main.js import markerWroclaw
```

Then I will just call it or receive response, but it is not working.

How can I import JS variable into python?